# Scala's equivalent of pandas in Python or data.frame / data.table in R

Tags: scala, dataframe

Python has `pandas` and R has `data.table` as de facto standard libraries for data manipulation.

What is the equivalent for Scala?

Comment: [spark data frame](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html)?

Answer (score 7):

Try this library: https://saddle.github.io/ - it's a port of `pandas`

Comment: Seems like its not maintained anymore?

Comment: No idea. Lost touch with the author a few years ago